# Other ways than SessionAttribute in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC and I'm learning about SessionAttribute.

Does Spring support any others solution to store session rather than using only SessionAttributes?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why? Does it not work for you?

Comment: no , it works very good,but i think that having many solutions for one problem is always better

Comment: just to want to know if there are any other ways to do this

Comment: In Spring no other way,use J2EE and also can see regarding FlashAttributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always do it the JEE way:

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public String home(HttpSession session) {
    session.setAttribute("myparam", "myvalue");
    return "home";
}
```

Comment: J2EE is fine but he is asking any other way in Spring not in J2EE

Comment: I know, but Spring only offers the @SessionAttributes annotation for MVC session management. According to their API, [SessionAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html): "For permanent session attributes, e.g. a user authentication object, use the traditional session.setAttribute method instead".